# Existence of an integral

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, definite-integrals

Consider an integral:
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^0 e^{-x}f(x)dx.
$$
If $f(x)$ has compact support on the interval $[-A,A]$, is it sufficient to conclude that the integral I is finite?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any regularity condition on $f$?

Comment: More demands on $f$. E.g. it can have compact support and at the same time not be measurable. Then the integral is not defined properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. First of all you must assume $f$ measurable. But even then it is not true in general. Example
$$
f(x)=\max(-\frac{1}{x(x+1)},0),
$$
whose support is $[-1,0]$.